# Что не так с классом для создания VBO, VAO и EBO

Tags: c++, opengl

что я сделал не так в классе для создания VBO, VAO и EBO?

класс .h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class VO {
private:
    unsigned int VAO;
    unsigned int VBO;
public:
    void createVertexObjects(std::vector<float> vertices, int8_t verticesCount, std::vector<unsigned int> indices);
    void unBind();

    unsigned int getVAO() { return VAO; }

    ~VO();
};
```

класс .cpp:

```
#include "VertexObjects.h"
#include "GLAD/glad.h"

void VO::createVertexObjects(std::vector<float> vertices, int8_t verticesCount, std::vector<unsigned int> indices)
{
    unsigned int EBO;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,  verticesCount * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void VO::unBind()
{
     glBindVertexArray(0);
}

VO::~VO()
{
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
}
```

Данные для VBO и EBO:

1. Координаты вершин:

   ```
    std::vector<float> vertices = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };
   ```
2. Индексы для EBO:

   ```
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
   ```

Comment: 1. Почему не удаляете EBO в деструкторе? 2. `glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);` в декструкторе - зря, вдруг какой-то другой VAO прибинжен? Все равно VAO удалится, так что смысла в этом нет. 3. Недостает конструтора по умолчанию, который занулял бы поля. 4. Либо удалить копирующие операции, либо сделать нормальные перемещающие операции. 5. Индексы в EBO начинаются с 0, не с 1.

Comment: а нужно добавлять к глобальным переменным(VAO, VBO) "this->" если я хочу использовать этот класс и для других мешей?

Comment: Не понял, где в коде глобальные переменные? Что значит "для других мешей"? В смысле иметь больше одного экземпляра класса?

Comment: VAO, VBO и EBO(я только что объявил в .h файле)  не глобальные?

Comment: Так они ж внутри класса (EBO вообще внутри функции - не заметил сразу). Глобальные - это которые снаружи всего (или внутри namespace).

Comment: 1. Я не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду под 4 пунктом. 2. Хорошо, переменные не глобальные (я уже объявил EBO как член класса), тогда нужно ли добавлять "this->" перед VBO, VAO и EBO чтобы использовать этот класс для создания новых мешей. https://github.com/artemko22/Hyko_Engine.git - это мой проект на github, однако старая версия. Тут будут классы для создания примитивов(пока у меня только есть треугольник) и в этом классе я создаю VBO,VAO через их классы (EBO в этой версии еще нету и класс для создания VBO и VAO другой, так как я его сейчас переписываю), также там я рендерю этот треугольник

Comment: Я хочу с помощью этого класса создавать множество треугольников(как на пример в SFML) создавая новые объекты класса треугольника

Comment: однако рендерится только один треугольник, независимо от того сколько я объявлю объектов :(

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему. Раньше в классе треугольника, в функции "createVO()"(где и создавался VAO, VBO и EBO через функцию "VO::createVertexObject()") я объявлял объект класса VO, теперь же я объявил объект как член класса(в .h файле). И заработало!
Но я так и не понял почему тогда оно не работало.